# SendChangePhoneCodeRequest does not send the code

Tags: telethon

```
async def change_phone(client, phone):
    await client.connect()
    hash = await client(functions.account.SendChangePhoneCodeRequest(
        phone_number=phone,
        settings=types.CodeSettings(
            allow_flashcall=False,
            current_number=False,
            allow_app_hash=False,
            allow_missed_call=False,
            allow_firebase=False
        )
    ))
    code = input()
    hash = hash.phone_code_hash
    await client(functions.account.ChangePhoneRequest(
        phone_number=phone,
        phone_code_hash=hash,
        phone_code=code
    ))
```

It doesn't work.
does telegram even send the code through third-party clients?